# gruntjs: do I need to install dependency plugins for each project?

Tags: gruntjs

I am recently using gruntjs. It's amazing. I am using version 0.4.5

Every time when I am going to create a new project, do I need to install all dependency plugins that I needed? like grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-sass etc.

Basically, I use 4-5 plugins for each project and just wonder to know that if there is away to use it globally.

Going through grunt doc, they said I have to install dependencies locally, that means all plugins for each project?

:(

Comment: I am also new to npm concepts but have you tried something like `npm install -g grunt-contrib-uglify`. I believe it should work.

Comment: In general, that's a feature, not a bug. This may be helpful: http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation

Comment: @turhanco but when I run grunt, it always look for local Npm module. How can I declare so it will look for global?

Comment: There is an answer here, I think it is what you need :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795171/how-to-make-grunt-deploy-use-global-npm-modules-instead-of-local-ones][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795171/how-to-make-grunt-deploy-use-global-npm-modules-instead-of-local-ones