# Issues with Grunt loadNpmTasks and not finding the module

Tags: gruntjs

I am new to Grunt. I have my grunt (verified version and such) and I see my needed Npmtasks in my "node_modules" folder. But, when I try to run the grunt, it fails because the task module can't be found.

grunt default -v

I have my node_modules installed in my drive:

```
C:\Users\NoBody\node_modules
```

Usually, this isn't an issue. BUT, it appear that where I am doing my dev:

```
C:\users\Nobody\Desktop\Development\GruntExamples\
```

can't locate my needed NpmTask modules. When I move the files into: 
`C:\Users\Nobody` -- everything works.. But, I don't want to do my dev there.

I tried adding the path to NpmTaks like so:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks("../../../../grunt-contrib-clean");
```

I tried a few other "paths", nothing is working. Is there a "path" declaration I can add to my grunt file that will let my task resolve where it needs to?

note: I tried npm install grunt-contrib-clean --save-dev (no luck), I tried grunt-contrib-clean -g (no luck)..

But just like I mentioned. If I move my files inside the same root dir that my node_modules sit, it works... but again, I don't want to do my dev here.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Using symbolic links seems to be an option ([How to make Grunt Deploy use global NPM modules instead of local ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795171/how-to-make-grunt-deploy-use-global-npm-modules-instead-of-local-ones)), although I have never tried it.

However, I would advise against using a global `node_modules` location. My reasoning:

- Local copies of your dependencies do not affect each other. Updating `karma`, for instance, in one of your code bases does not affect the others. Trying out a new version of `grunt` will not harm anybody else.
- Some people say that you also should ship your `node_modules` folder ([link](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node_modules-folder-into-git)) - a thing that you can only do if you have a local copy

Comment: hmm, perhaps because I am new to grunt -- but it is normal protocal to have all your node_modules in the local dir, and then bundle it all up? I was just thinking that that is a lot of duplication of required npm's.

Comment: Enormous duplication, lots of space used up etc. But tackling the ages-old dependency problem in a very robust way.