# npm - unable to find local grunt or karma I just installed via package.json

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gruntjs

I cannot find `grunt`, though I just installed it via `package.json`

My setup:

```
ph@vm:~$ uname -a
Linux vm 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ph@vm:~$ which node
/usr/bin/node
ph@vm:~$ which npm
/usr/bin/npm
ph@vm:~$ node -v
v4.4.3
ph@vm:~$ npm -v
3.8.6
ph@vm:~$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
NODE_ENV="development"
#NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
```

My `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
   ....
    "pretest": "grunt lint",
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js",
   ...
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",

  },
  "dependencies": {
    ....
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    ...

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "karma": "~0.12.37",
    ....
    "protractor": "~2.5.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

### Problem

After a `npm install` in the folder of `package.json` all the required packages are installed correctly in `node_modules`.

Running:

`npm run protractor` => works fine

`npm run pretest` = fails:
AND
`npm run test` => fails:
WITH

```
> grunt lint

sh: 1: grunt: not found
```

What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: In order to use `grunt` as a cli command, you need to also install the `grunt-cli` dependency.

Comment: Install grunt-cli did not fix it, still not found

Answer (score 2):

I hope you install grunt globally . Thats why you getting error unable to find local grunt or karma. Sometimes We need both globally or locally so first install the grunt

> Globally

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

After installation process done then you move to project folder and install the grunt locally.

> locally

```
npm install grunt --save
npm install grunt-cli
```

For more info [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795171/how-to-make-grunt-deploy-use-global-npm-modules-instead-of-local-ones)

Comment: Why should I install grunt globally? I want to install once run "npm install" and all my dep should work. That is how our project is set up.

Comment: Install this globally and you'll have access to the grunt command anywhere on your system.

Comment: I did install it now globally, but still it says: grunt: command not found. I think there is a problem with my paths?

Comment: can you share your paths

Comment: After installing nvm and using 4.0, now it works but only after installing grunt-cli globally. There must be another way though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -g grunt-cli`

This will install the grunt-cli tools, but also note the `-g` switch which installs it globally rather than just to your local `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Did not help, still not found

Comment: Check which directory grunt-cli was globally installed to and make that the PATH environment variable contains that directory. Usually C:\Users\USERNAME\npm or C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming